# How to use JSON with server? (Android)

Tags: android, json

I have to do something for school. I have to make an app for a store which sells locks. We have been given code for a server app which works with JSON. Now I have a question, I know how I can parse JSON from a URL into a ListView in Android. But this is new for me. How can I parse JSON from the information I have been given?

This is the code for the data of the locks (SlotData):

```
     package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

 import java.util.HashMap;

  public class SlotData
  {
//singleton
private static SlotData _instance;
public static SlotData getInstance()
{
    if( _instance == null )
        _instance = new SlotData();

    return _instance;
}



private String[] sloten = { "Sleutel slotsystemen", "RFID slotsystemen", "Biometrische slotsystemen"};
private HashMap<String, String> slotInfo;
private HashMap<String, String> slotInfoBeknopt;

private SlotData()
{   
    slotInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    slotInfoBeknopt = new HashMap<String,String>();

    slotInfo.put( "Sleutel slotsystemen", "De meest eenvoudige vorm van beveiliging zijn sloten die per sleutel geopend kunnen worden. Dit is een relatief goedkoop systeem maar brengt enige veiligheidsproblemen met zich mee. Voor beveiliging van ruimtes die weinig waardevolle zaken bevatten is dit systeem een uitstekende uitkomst." );
    slotInfo.put( "RFID slotsystemen", "RFID authenticatie is met de huidige techniek snel en gemakkelijk te implementeren om elke ruimte af te sluiten. Dankzij de digitalisering kunnen gebruikers getraceerd worden en bestaat de mogelijkheid een geschiedenis van ruimtegebruik aan te leggen. Dit resulteert in verhoogde beveiliging." );
    slotInfo.put( "Biometrische slotsystemen", "Biometrische authenticatie en authorizatie is de meest geavanceerde vorm van beveiliging. Dit systeem werkt nagenoeg feilloos en garandeerd een zeer hoge veiligheid van uw waardevolle bezittingen. Biometrische authorizatie kan op verschillende niveaus worden toegepast, van vingerafdruk tot irisscan." );

    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "Sleutel slotsystemen", "Eenvoudig, snel en goedkoop uw bezit achter slot en grendel!" );
    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "RFID slotsystemen", "Digitale beveiliging voor 100% zekerheid!" );
    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "Biometrische slotsystemen", "Authenticatie en authorizatie op persoonlijk niveau!" );
}

public String[] getSloten()
{
    return sloten;
}

public String getInformatie( String slot )
{
    return slotInfo.get( slot );
}

public String getInformatieBeknopt( String slot )
{
    return slotInfoBeknopt.get( slot );
}
 }
```

Code from Server class:

```
   package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;

 import javax.swing.JTextArea;


 public class Server implements Runnable
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Thread thread;
private boolean stop;
private JTextArea textArea;

public Server( JTextArea textArea )
{
    this.textArea = textArea;
    this.textArea.setEditable( false );
    this.stop = false;

    try
    {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 4444 );
        this.thread = new Thread( this );
        this.thread.start();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void requestStop()
{
    this.stop = true;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    this.textArea.append( "Waiting for clients\n" );

    while( this.stop == false )
    {
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            new ClientCommunicator( this.textArea, clientSocket );
        }

        catch( IOException e )
        {
            this.textArea.append( "Failed to continue listening to clients\n" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 }
```

DeSleutelaar class (De Sleutelaar is the name of the store)

```
  package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class DeSleutelaar extends JFrame
 {
private Server server;

public DeSleutelaar()
{
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    this.setSize( 400, 400 );
    this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
    textArea.setEditable( false );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
    this.add( scrollPane );

    this.setVisible( true );

    server = new Server( textArea );
}


@Override
public void finalize()
{
    server.requestStop();
}


public static void main( String[] args )
{
    new DeSleutelaar();
}
}
```

And the ClientCommunicator class:

```
 package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

  public class ClientCommunicator implements Runnable
 {
private Socket clientSocket;
private JTextArea textArea;
private PrintWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;

public ClientCommunicator( JTextArea textArea, Socket clientSocket )
{
    this.textArea = textArea;
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

    Thread thread = new Thread( this );
    thread.start();
}


@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        this.connect();
        this.converse();
    }

    catch( IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    this.close();
}


public void connect() throws IOException
{
    this.writer = new PrintWriter(
        this.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true
    );

    this.reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            this.clientSocket.getInputStream()
        )
    );
}

private String processInput( String input )
{
    String answer = "Could not parse sent json string";

    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( input );

        if( jsonObject != null )
        {
            if( jsonObject.has("slotenlijst") )
            {   
                answer = getSloten();
            }

            if( jsonObject.has("informatie") )
            {   
                answer = getInformatie( jsonObject.get("informatie").toString() );
            }

            if( jsonObject.has("informatiebeknopt") )
            {   
                answer = getInformatieBeknopt( jsonObject.get("informatiebeknopt").toString() );
            }

            if( jsonObject.has("aanvraag") )
            {   
                answer = bestel( (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("aanvraag") );
            }
        }
    }

    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return answer;
}

private void converse() throws IOException
{
    String line = null;
    String outputLine = null;
    writer.println(outputLine);

    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null) {
        textArea.append( line );
        outputLine = processInput( line );
        writer.println(outputLine);
    }

    this.close();
}


private void close()
{
    try
    {
        this.writer.close();
        this.reader.close();
        this.clientSocket.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




//data

private String getSloten()
{
    SlotData data = SlotData.getInstance();

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < data.getSloten().length; i++ )
    {
        String category = data.getSloten()[i];
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put( "naam", category );
        array.put( obj );
    }

    return array.toString();
}


private String getInformatie( String slot )
{
    SlotData slotData = SlotData.getInstance();

    String informatie = slotData.getInformatie(slot);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put( "informatie", informatie );

    return obj.toString();
}


private String getInformatieBeknopt( String slot )
{
    SlotData slotData = SlotData.getInstance();

    String informatieBeknopt = slotData.getInformatieBeknopt(slot);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put( "informatiebeknopt", informatieBeknopt );

    return obj.toString();
}


private String bestel( JSONArray aanvraagInfo )
{
    JSONObject aanvraag = (JSONObject) aanvraagInfo.get(0);
    JSONObject koper = (JSONObject) aanvraagInfo.get(1);

    String slotNaam = aanvraag.get( "slotnaam" ).toString();

    String koperNaam = koper.get( "kopernaam" ).toString();
    String koperAdres = koper.get( "koperadres" ).toString();
    String koperTelNr = koper.get( "kopertelnr" ).toString();
    String koperEmail = koper.get( "koperemail" ).toString();

    textArea.append("\n");
    textArea.append( "Nieuwe bestelling: " + slotNaam + " voor " +
                     koperNaam + "\n" );
    textArea.append( koperAdres + "\n" );
    textArea.append( koperTelNr + "\n" );
    textArea.append( koperEmail + "\n" );

    return "Bestelling ontvangen, binnen 3 dagen komt een erkent sleutelaar bij u langs!";
}
  }
```

Sorry for all the information, but I only need a step in the right direction. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you don't need to do the server side code as it seems it is done. Do you have any url/api, from which you can access the json data?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @MohammadArman No, I don't have an url or api. But what I don't get is how to parse the JSON data in the application.

Comment: I have shared a short example of JSON parsing in the following answer. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a JSONObject like below:

```
{
    "username":"arman",
    "password":"1234"
}
```

In order to parse it do the following.

```
try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response1);
        String username = obj.getString("username");
        String Password = obj.getString("password");
    } 
catch (Throwable t) {

}
```

For detail Understanding: You can take a look on [this blog](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).